# Xpath to get a child node value

Tags: xpath

How can I get the values of all nodes called "title" from the XML below ?

```
<bookstore>
<bookA>
 <title> Title Book A</title>
 <desc> Book A </desc>
<bookA>

<bookB>
 <title> Title Book B</title>
 <desc> Book B </desc>
<bookB>
</bookstore>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try: `bookstore//title`

`//` means any child (including grandchildren) named `title`

By the way, you didn't close off the book elements.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be:

```
bookstore/*/title
```